# Bash rename 360 000 files using find -exec

Tags: bash, find, rename, exec

I've got around 360 000 files like:

```
./001/1/1.jpg
./001/1/2.jpg
./001/2/1.jpg
./002/1/1.jpg
./003/1/1.jpg
...
pattern: [60 dirs]/[1000 subdirs]/[4-10 files].jpg
```

I want to rename files using `rename` for example from *.jpg to *.jpeg. I can't do it with single `rename`, because I get the error argument list is too long.

Searching for solution, I figured out this, but it renames nothing:

`find -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec rename -n 's/jpg/jpeg/' {}/* \;`

When I check if the `{}` is expanded replacing rename with echo:

`find -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -type d -exec echo "rename -n 's/jpg/jpeg/' {}/*" \;`

I get expected result:

```
rename -n 's/jpg/jpeg/' ./061/61430/*
rename -n 's/jpg/jpeg/' ./061/61431/*
...
```

If I run any of these rename commands, I rename works. So the should be problem with the `{}`.

Thank you for help!

Comment: and if try to escape: `\{\}`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
find  | prename 's/\.jpg$/.jpeg/'
```

or if you have oder files in the currunt directory

```
find 0[0-9][0-9] | prename 's/\.jpg$/.jpeg/'
```

Comment: It doesn't really work but it made me remaking the script so now the problem is solved. Thank you.

Comment: @koubic, successfully remaking your own script is even better than a working suggested solution!  What is the problem of this version?

Comment: Ok, I'm sorry, it actually works. It's just a different approach to my original question. Your approach is slower, because `rename` process has to be run for every single file. My approach wanted to put a subdirectory to rename so `rename` would be executed severalfold less often. But I eventually used it because speed wasn't a problem on the real server.

Comment: @koubic, thank you for everything. In my approach, rename process should be executed only once. If you can, it would be interesting to "time" the solutions (I'm curious about the time taken for renaming such a big number of files!)

Comment: This, unfortunately, won't work correctly if any of the filenames contain a newline.  A workaround is to use `-print0` with `find` for NUL-separated output and run `prename` (with full path specified) using `perl -0` - e.g. `find -print0 | perl -0 /usr/bin/prename 's/\.jpg$/.jpeg/'`.    `prename` itself should (but doesn't) have a `-0` option...I've reported this as a bug to rt-cpan.org.

Answer (score 4):

In the first instance, `*` is expanded by the shell before it gets to `rename` (if it is expanded at all - I doubt anything matches `{}/*`), and if it isn't expanded, the command that is executed is `rename` with the three arguments `-n`, `s/jpg/jpeg/` and `some/path/*`. That last argument is not the name of an existing file so `rename` does nothing.

Without shell globbing, the path is useless to `rename`.

So, instead, do:

```
find -maxdepth 3 -mindepth 3 -type f -iname '*.jpg' -exec rename -n 's/jpg$/jpeg/i' {} +
```

Use `find`'s ability to build command lines as long as is possible with `+` instead of `;`.

Answer (score 1):

You should not specify `type d` unless you want to rename only directories. To change extensions `.jpg` to `.jpeg` try

```
find . -maxdepth 2 -mindepth 2 -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'echo mv -- "$0" "${0%%.jpg}.jpeg"' {} \;
```

Remove `echo` if you like what you see on the screen.

Comment: This answer is amazing on so many levels. It includes a "testing" mode and it uses  primitive commands.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative way should `rename` happen to be missing:

```
find 0[0-6][0-9] -name "*.jpg" -exec sh -c 'for i do echo mv "$i" "${i%g}eg"; done' sh {} +
```

Answer (score 0):

Using cygwin, my version of rename does not have the regex replacement, nor does its `rename [options] expression replacement file...` syntax seem to work.  Also, the bash suggestions fail with

```
... -c: line 0: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `"'
... -c: line 1: syntax error: unexpected end of file
```

Alas...  there is always perl:

```
perl -MFile::Find -e 'find(sub{return unless /^(.*)\.jpg$/;`mv $_ $1.jpeg`}, ".")'
```

Comment: The `rename` mentioned in many of these answers is written in `perl`. See http://tips.webdesign10.com/files/rename.pl.txt for one implementation.

Comment: @roaima, how do you know that?  On my system (the latest cygwin), the `rename` found in my default path is "The   rename   command   is   part   of   the   util-linux   package  and  is  available  from  ftp://ftp.kernel.org/pub/linux/utils/util-linux/" and is a binary file, not a perl script...

Comment: I also have Cygwin on a number of Windows platforms. There are two different implementations of `rename` and yours as described is the "other" one.