# Change name of all PNG files in directory recursively

Tags: directory, recursive, mv

I have a directory called `assets` and it contains a file structure similar to this:

```
├── a
│   ├── b
│   │   ├── c.png
│   │   └── d.png
│   └── b2
│       ├── e.png
│       ├── f.png
│       └── g.png
└── a2
    └── b3
        └── h.png
```

How can I change the name of all the images in this structure to the pattern `NAME_old.png` where `NAME` is the original name of the file? (For example, `c.png` would be changed to `c_old.png`)

I have a feeling that it has something to do with sed/awk/grep and using pipes, but I haven't the faintest idea how to use these tools and reading documentation doesn't really help.

Answer (score 4):

Using `find`

```
find assets -type d -exec sh -c '
    for n in "$1"/*.png; do
        test -f "$n" && mv "$n" "${n%.png}_old.png"
    done' sh {} ';'
```

This `find` command looks for *directories* in or under the `assets` directory.  For each found directory, it executes the following short shell script:

```
for n in "$1"/*.png; do
    test -f "$n" && mv "$n" "${n%.png}_old.png"
done
```

where `$1` will expand to the path to the found directory.  The script will iterate over all filenames matching `*.png` in the directory and replace the `.png` filename suffix with `_old.png` using a variable substitution.

The `test -f` makes sure that we're operating on existing files. This is needed because if a directory dose *not* contain any files matching `*.png` (as in the `assets`, `a` and `a2` directories), then that pattern will remain unexpanded in `$n`.

Alternatively, and shorter,

```
find assets -type f -name '*.png' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do mv "$n" "${n%.png}_old.png"; done' sh {} +
```

Testing:

```
$ mkdir -p assets/a{,2}/b{,2,3}
$ touch assets/a{,2}/b{,2,3}/{a,b,c,d}.png
$ tree
.
`-- assets
    |-- a
    |   |-- b
    |   |   |-- a.png
    |   |   |-- b.png
    |   |   |-- c.png
    |   |   `-- d.png
    |   |-- b2
    |   |   |-- a.png
    |   |   |-- b.png
    |   |   |-- c.png
    |   |   `-- d.png
    |   `-- b3
    |       |-- a.png
    |       |-- b.png
    |       |-- c.png
    |       `-- d.png
    `-- a2
        |-- b
        |   |-- a.png
        |   |-- b.png
        |   |-- c.png
        |   `-- d.png
        |-- b2
        |   |-- a.png
        |   |-- b.png
        |   |-- c.png
        |   `-- d.png
        `-- b3
            |-- a.png
            |-- b.png
            |-- c.png
            `-- d.png

9 directories, 24 files
```

(`find` command executed here)

```
$ tree
.
`-- assets
    |-- a
    |   |-- b
    |   |   |-- a_old.png
    |   |   |-- b_old.png
    |   |   |-- c_old.png
    |   |   `-- d_old.png
    |   |-- b2
    |   |   |-- a_old.png
    |   |   |-- b_old.png
    |   |   |-- c_old.png
    |   |   `-- d_old.png
    |   `-- b3
    |       |-- a_old.png
    |       |-- b_old.png
    |       |-- c_old.png
    |       `-- d_old.png
    `-- a2
        |-- b
        |   |-- a_old.png
        |   |-- b_old.png
        |   |-- c_old.png
        |   `-- d_old.png
        |-- b2
        |   |-- a_old.png
        |   |-- b_old.png
        |   |-- c_old.png
        |   `-- d_old.png
        `-- b3
            |-- a_old.png
            |-- b_old.png
            |-- c_old.png
            `-- d_old.png

9 directories, 24 files
```

Comment: Why spawn a shell for each directory?  Why not just use `find assets -type f -name '*.png' -exec sh -c 'for f do mv "$f" "${f%.png}_old.png"; done' sh {} +`?

Comment: @Wildcard You mean for each file? (I'm assuming you are referring to the second `find`).  Yes, I have updated that now. And thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Use [prename together with find](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/177705/bash-rename-360-000-files-using-find-exec/177708#177708):

```
find . -type f -name '*.png' -exec prename 's/\.png$/_old.png/' {} +
```

Answer (score 1):

#### Without `find`

Given the fixed directory structure, you can use wildcards for directories:

```
rename -n s/.png/_old.png/ */*/*.png
```

(change `-n` to `-v` to actually run the command).

If the PNG's are at different directory levels, you can still avoid `find`:

```
shopt -s globstar
rename -n s/.png/_old.png/ **/*.png
```

(with `globstar` set, `**` matches any number of directory levels)

On Debian and derivatives, `prename` is called `rename`, but it's the same command.