# Will we ever "find" files whose names are changed by "find"? Why not?

Tags: find

While answering [an older question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/328977/change-name-of-all-png-files-in-directory-recursively) it struck me that it seems `find`, in the following example, potentially would process files multiple times:

```
find dir -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.txt}_hello.txt"' sh {} ';'
```

or the more efficient

```
find dir -type f -name '*.txt' \
    -exec sh -c 'for n; do mv "$n" "${n%.txt}_hello.txt"; done' sh {} +
```

The command finds `.txt` files and changes their filename suffix from `.txt` to `_hello.txt`.

While doing so, the directories will start accumulating new files whose names matches the `*.txt` pattern, namely these `_hello.txt` files.

Question: Why are they not actually processed by `find`? Because in my experience they aren't, and we don't want them to be either as it would introduce a sort of infinite loop. This is also the case with `mv` replaced by `cp`, by the way.

The [POSIX standard says](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799.2016edition/utilities/find.html) (my emphasis)

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory hierarchy being searched **it is unspecified whether or not `find` includes that file in its search**.

Since it's unspecified whether new files will be included, maybe a safer approach would be

```
find dir -type d -exec sh -c '
    for n in "$1"/*.txt; do
        test -f "$n" && mv "$n" "${n%.txt}_hello.txt"
    done' sh {} ';'
```

Here, we don't look for files but for directories, and the `for` loop of the internal `sh` script evaluates its range once before the first iteration, so we don't have the same potential issue.

The GNU `find` manual does not explicitly say anything about this and neither does the OpenBSD `find` manual.

Comment: *it is unspecified whether or not* - I wonder why do the authors of `find` utility not get concerned of such tricky behavior

Comment: `readdir` has essentially the same specification. I would expect it to be potentially filesystem-specific, even (loading one block of directory entries at a time is pretty reasonable).

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, it's unspecified in the POSIX specification.  That doesn't mean the authors of `find` utility don't get concerned with the behavior.  It means it's left to the authors of any given implementation of the `find` utility how to handle that case, rather than being specified.  (If that seems unclear I recommend you fully clear up the words "specification" and "implementation" as they apply to software.)

Comment: @Wildcard, words "specification" and "implementation" are clear. A cite from the question: *The GNU find manual does not explicitly say anything about this and neither does the OpenBSD find manual*. So, that's bad ... and I shouldn't be compelled to like that

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, ah, I see.  Your first comment quoted the POSIX spec so I wasn't sure.  I wouldn't say it's bad, though (that the `find` devs don't mention it).  As described in [ikkachu's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/423971/135943), that's a filesystem level behavior, not even specified in the `readdir()` system call spec.  There are going to be race conditions no matter what.

Comment: @Wildcard, I like `find` tool ... but don't like implementation discrepancies (let's call it idealism)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Can `find` find files that were created while it was walking the directory?

In brief: Yes, but it depends on the implementation. It's probably best to write the conditions so that already processed files are ignored.

As mentioned, POSIX makes no guarantees either way, like it also makes [no guarantees on the underlying `readdir()` system call](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/readdir.html):

> If a file is removed from or added to the directory after the most recent call to `opendir()` or `rewinddir()`, whether a subsequent call to `readdir()` returns an entry for that file is unspecified.

---

I tested the `find` on my Debian (GNU find, Debian package version `4.6.0+git+20161106-2`). `strace` showed that it read the full directory before doing anything.

Browsing the source code a bit more makes it seem that GNU find uses parts of gnulib to read the directories, and there's this in [gnulib/lib/fts.c](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/lib/fts.c?id=646a44e1b190c4a7f6a9f32c63230c619e38d251#n135) (`gl/lib/fts.c` in the `find` tarball):

```
/* If possible (see max_entries, below), read no more than this many directory
   entries at a time.  Without this limit (i.e., when using non-NULL
   fts_compar), processing a directory with 4,000,000 entries requires ~1GiB
   of memory, and handling 64M entries would require 16GiB of memory.  */
#ifndef FTS_MAX_READDIR_ENTRIES
# define FTS_MAX_READDIR_ENTRIES 100000
#endif
```

I changed that limit to 100, and did

```
mkdir test; cd test; touch {0000..2999}.foo
find . -type f -exec sh -c 'mv "$1" "${1%.foo}.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar"' sh {} \; -print
```

resulting in such hilarious results as this file, which got renamed five times:

```
1046.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar.barbarbarbarbarbarbarbar
```

---

Obviously, a very large directory (more than 100 000 entries) would be needed to trigger that effect on a default build of GNU find, but a trivial readdir+process loop without caching would be even more vulnerable.

In theory, if the OS always added renamed files last in the order where `readdir()` returned them, a simple implementation like that could even fall into an endless loop.

On Linux, `readdir()` in the C library is implemented through the `getdents()` system call, which already returns multiple directory entries at one go. Which means that later calls to `readdir()` might return files that were already removed, but for very small directories you'd effectively get a snapshot of the starting state. I don't know about other systems.

In the above test, I did the renames to a longer file name on purpose: to prevent the file name from being overwritten in-place. No matter, the same test on a same-length rename also did double and triple renames. If and how this matters would of course depend on the filesystem internals.

Considering all this, it's probably prudent to avoid the whole issue by making the `find` expression *not* match the files that were already processed. That is, to add `-name "*.foo"` in my example or `! -name "*_hello.txt"` to the command in the question.

Comment: This would seem to indicate that the default GNU `find` indeed would have issues with directories holding more than 100K files (or maybe entries of any type?) and that my precaution is not as silly as I first thought. (well, having 100K files in a directory is in itself a bit silly)  I will look for similar code in my native OpenBSD `find` as soon as I get a chance.

Comment: Interesting. Better be more careful with `find` regexps in the future.

Comment: Actually, I wonder if the alternative approach would work on such a directory... expanding a glob to more than 100K pathnames? That would have its own issues.